# I am having this error when I use npx create-react-app eroor ENOTDIR

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, linux-mint, npx

I have this error when I use npx create react app on my linux mint

npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js/lib
npm ERR! errno -20
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, lstat '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js/lib'

I have unistall and reinstall node and npm I have the version 9.5.1 and the npx 9.5.1

I have checked an answer for a path but i cant do it as i have no shell file or something , im wondering if you can help me , as I cant create next app without npx